# I create Buttons Using array so I want to get text value of button to variable when clicked a button of a array how can I do this?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void CreatingNewButtons()
    {
        int horizotal = 30;
        int vertical = 30;
        DataTable dt = Product.getAllProducts();
        Button[] buttonArray = new Button[dt.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string name = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            string price = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            // byte[] getImg = dt.Rows[i][2];
            buttonArray[i] = new Button();
            buttonArray[i].Size = new Size(110, 110);
            buttonArray[i].Location = new Point(horizotal, vertical);
            buttonArray[i].Text = "" + name + "  Rs :" + price + "";
            if ((i == 5) || (i == 11) || (i == 17) || (i == 23) || (i == 29) ||
             (i == 35)) //|| (i == 62) || (i == 71))
            {
                vertical = 30;
                horizotal = horizotal + 130;//depaththe ida
            }
            else
                vertical = vertical + 130;
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);
            tabPage1.AutoScroll = true;
        }

    }
```

Using this code I create the button array and set buttons text from database as above. Now I want to get that text to string when clicked a button.

Comment: You forget to add an event handler for the click over the button. Without it your code cannot know which button has been clicked

Comment: You may create a common eventhandler for the button you are creating in the loop. In the code that handles the event, you can refer to `sender` variable to evaluate the button which triggered the click event, using which you can inspect its `Text` property.

Comment: As a side note, I suggest you to look at the [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=netframework-4.7.2) control to ease the burden to add the buttons and keep them in the proper position

Answer (score 0):

First assign the event handler.

```
buttonArray[i].Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
```

Then in the method, detect the click.

```
    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //To Do - Click Event
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        MessageBox.Show(btn.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just `+= ButtonClick;`, no need to write so much

Comment: Thank You So much Problem Solved..